# giving view permission to a room resource - exchange 2016

Tags: exchange-2016

I've defined a room resource in the exchange admin (web) 
the users can allocate the room, but when they look at the calender of the room they only see "occupied" state -

how can I let everyone see the details of the meeting? (organizer and subject) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run the following commands and check again:

```
Set-calendarprocessing RoomMailbox -DeleteSubject $false 

Set-MailboxfolderPermission "RoomMailbox:\calendar" -User Default -AccessRights Reviewer
```